# Prevent MySQL to connect Master

Tags: mysql, replication

We switched a slave to master today and after restarting the new master it tries to connect to the old master.

Even with `stop slave;`, it tries to connect after restarting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`RESET SLAVE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reset-slave.html) to tell the instance to forget about its former master.

The exact commands to run depend on your MySQL version.

For MySQL versions prior to 5.5:

```
stop slave;
change master to MASTER_HOST='';
reset slave;
```

For MySQL 5.5 and above:

```
stop slave;
reset slave all;
```

Either way, make sure that you also remove any “master-” statements from my.cnf if you have them.